# Change node env var in Cypress

Tags: vue.js, cypress

I'm using Cypress, and I have in my code "process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL". This variable is defined in my .env.development file.
I want to modify this variable when I'm running Cypress.

How to do that ?

Note : To lanch Cypress, I use the command ./node_modules/.bin/cypress open

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in the command line and it worked for me:

```
CYPRESS_BASE_URL=$VUE_APP_API_URL ./node_modules/.bin/cypress open
```

More info in the documentation:
[Cypress environment variable](https://docs.cypress.io/es/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#We-can-move-this-into-a-Cypress-environment-variable)